# Python, re-entering the `with` block

Tags: python

I am currently working on an import script that import listings from a database that regularly shuts down every 15 mins for re-snap.

I have created a `with` block as below to look after the retry mechanism when creating connections:

```
class DBRetryController(object):
    conn_obj = None
    connection = None
    cursor = None
    retry_count_down = None
    sleep_time = None

    def __init__(self, conn_obj, retry_count_down=5, sleep_time=10):
        self.conn_obj = conn_obj
        self.retry_count_down = retry_count_down
        self.sleep_time = sleep_time

    def __enter__(self):
        ex = None
        while self.retry_count_down > 0:
            try:
                if hasattr(self.conn_obj, '__call__'):
                    self.connection = self.conn_obj()
                else:
                    self.connection = self.conn_obj
                self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
                self.retry_count_down = False
            except OperationalError as ex:
                log.warning('Caught db error, possibly due to sql server gone away, retrying in a few moment')
                self.retry_count_down -= 1
                time.sleep(self.sleep_time)
        if ex:
            raise ex
        return self.connection, self.cursor

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        try:
            self.cursor.close()
            self.connection.close()
        except:
            pass

        if value:
            raise value
```

And use as below:

```
with DBRetryController(self.connection) as (_, cursor):
    cursor.execute(self.LISTING_QUERY)
```

But the problem is the server can shutdown during execution of the query, is it possible to modifying the `DBRetryController` to make the nested block of code to re-enter?

Comment: _to make the nested block of code to re-enter_. May I ask you to explain a little more what do you mean by _to re-enter_?

Comment: basically re-execute from the beginning from `__enter__` to nested block.

Comment: Can't you define a global counter in your program and increase it by one at beginning of `__enter__` method and reduced it by 1 at the end of it. and in the line after calling the `cursor.execute(self.LISTING_QUERY)` check the value to be the same value at start of program (if the are not equal, you need to call the method agian)?

Comment: don't think you can...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you can use such a scheme:

```
notCompleted = 1
class TestClass():
    def run(self):
        global notCompleted
        notCompleted = 1
        #do_something here
        notCompleted = 0


test =  TestClass()
test.run()
while(notCompleted):
    test.run()
```

Let assume that I want to be sure, even if any error occure during execution of `run()` method, my program will retry to finish to run it complete again. The `notCompleted` is `1` by default. when I call the `run` method at the beginning I assign `1` to it and at the end of my `run` method I assigned `0` to it. Anywhere inside the `run()` if I have any problem, in the while loop the function will called again.

I think you need to add a `Try...Catch` too.

Comment: Thanks for trying but this is not the solution I am looking for.